# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de implementar WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Tengo duda al respecto del WCF al momento de su implementacion que seria lo adecuado crear WSDL por cada entidad que tiene el sistema ejemplo ClienteService un WSDL en el cual por lo general lleve los metodos CRUD o un solo WSDL que se denomine por ejemplo ErpService y que contenga todos los Metodos que interactuen con todas las Entidades existentes del sistema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para mí los Servicios WCF son 
son una encapsulación lógica de una funcionalidad del negocio. Con respecto a tus dos propuestas, yo iría un poco más allá y realizaría la implementación basándonos en bloques funcionales y no en entidades.Por ejemplo, un servicio de Inventario (InventoryServices), de Validaciones (ValidationService), de Ventas (SalesService), de Compras (PurchaseService) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de como hayas diseñado el sistema.

Yo en mi caso tengo la capa WCF que afecta a todas las entidades y es la unica que tiene acceso a la lógica del negocio.

Mi aplicacion WinForms sigue la siguiente estructura.

APP(Cliente Winforms) -> WCF -> BLL (Negocio) -> DAL (Datos)

de esta forma todos los procesos se ejecutan en el lado del servidor a través del WCF

Saludos,